# Where is the number of observations per level stored in a Cox regression object?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival, cox

I need to extract into a new column the number of observations per level from a Cox regression object. If I run:

```
res <- coxph(Surv(age, status) ~ score, data = df)
res %>% tbl_regression(exp = T) %>% add_n(location = 'level')
```

I get a similar table:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rasDU.png)
([Credit](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/add_n_regression.html))

Evidently, add_n() takes the number of observations from somewhere.

I looked at the object but I only saw where the total number of observations is stored, not per level. I googled but nothing relevant came up.

Comment: The short answer is that it isn't stored inside the model. The number of obs per level is _calculated_ inside `tbl_regression`, ultimately using `broom.helpers:::model_get_n.coxph`. It is stored as part of the `table_body` member of the `tbl_regression` output. It works via `model.frame`. You could do the same yourself quite easily by doing `table(model.frame(res)[[2]])`

Comment: TL;DNR : `add_n()` just tabulates factor/categorical variables.

Comment: @AllanCameron exactly what I needed, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by @AllanCameron in the comments:

> The short answer is that it isn't stored inside the model. The number
> of obs per level is calculated inside tbl_regression, ultimately using
> broom.helpers:::model_get_n.coxph. It is stored as part of the
> table_body member of the tbl_regression output. It works via
> model.frame. You could do the same yourself quite easily by doing
> table(model.frame(res)[[2]])